# Optaplanner: Limit Max distance Traveled by any Vehicle

Tags: routes, distance, drools, optaplanner

I am working on a Project which has a Battery Operated Vehicles. As we know they can only travel a limited distance. We are using those vehicle to Pick the packets from Customers. The Algo is working fine and giving results which vehicle can go and Pick from which customer. We are using road distance and calculated the matrix in VRP as our customer location is fixed.
Our problem is We require the Vehicle to return for re-charge before it takes next shipment. Our Vehicle can travel 80 KM in one recharge. So this will become hard constraint. How can we make Capacity and Maximum distance traveled by vehicle as hard constraint.

We are not able to get that done. If we check the Distance traveled at every addition of the customer in vehicle . then the system slows down as most of the Routes are not feasible between customers. We have put 9999 distance in our customer where the road distance is not feasible.

Please help in getting the right Constraint set.

Comment: If you're calling a remote service in your score function: Is the distance Euclidean or real-road distance? If it's real road-distance, precache the distance of every possible pair of locations in a lookup table. Use batch requests to graphhopper or google maps to fetch that real-word distances.

Comment: Dear Geoffery
We are using Real-Road Distance, We have done that with every pair and stored it in VRP File.
We are not able make Vehicle Travel only 80KM , It Goes Beyond that. How do we Restrict the Distance traveled by Vehicle should not exceed 80KM.

Comment: @Homer Have you solved this problem ? If positive ,then post the answer here. Thanks